# Sql Query Not Working in DB

Tags: sql

When i try to run sql query, its not working. i get error like,

[image]

My Query is below

> SELECT cpev.value as Name,cpe.sku,gp.value category_url, ea.value
>   image_path FROM catalog_product_entity cpe inner join (SELECT
>   entity_id,value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE
>   attribute_id="71") cpev on cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id inner join
>   (SELECT entity_id,value FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery) ea
>   on ea.entity_id=cpe.entity_id inner join( SELECT category_id,
>   product_id FROM catalog_category_product) eavv on cpe.entity_id
>   =eavv.product_id inner join( SELECT entity_id,value FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id='57') gp on
>   eavv.category_id=gp.entity_id

Comment: Add you query  which you are run in database.

Comment: SELECT cpev.value as Name,cpe.sku,gp.value category_url, ea.value image_path FROM catalog_product_entity cpe inner join (SELECT entity_id,value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id="71") cpev on cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id inner join (SELECT entity_id,value FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery) ea on ea.entity_id=cpe.entity_id inner join( SELECT category_id, product_id FROM catalog_category_product) eavv on cpe.entity_id =eavv.product_id inner join( SELECT entity_id,value FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id='57') gp on eavv.category_id=gp.entity_id

Comment: In localhost its working, but not working in my hosting site

Comment: Please specify magento version.

Comment: magento 1.9.2.3

Comment: this may possible that in your local and hosting site attribute_id is differ that is why you get this error. please check your attribute_id in at your hosting site

Comment: Have you try after indexing on hosting site ?

Comment: yes i am reindexing after hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your query is too havy for remote mysql server. Here is optimized query.

```
SELECT cpev.value as Name,cpe.sku,gp.value category_url, ea.value image_path 
FROM catalog_product_entity cpe 
inner join catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev on cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id and  cpev.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'name' and entity_type_id = 4)
inner join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery  ea on ea.entity_id=cpe.entity_id 
inner join catalog_category_product eavv on cpe.entity_id =eavv.product_id 
inner join catalog_category_entity_varchar gp on eavv.category_id=gp.entity_id and gp.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'url_key' and entity_type_id = 3)
```

if it will not work too, try to add "LIMIT 10" at the end

Answer (score 1):

Firstly **enable mysql's error log**  so you can find exact error

1.uncheck limit rows in in Edit → Preferences →SQL Queries

or

2.change specific timeouts.   **IN  MY MySQL WorkBench**

For me it was under Edit → Preferences → SQL Editor → DBMS connection read time out (in seconds): 600

Changed the value to 6000.
[image]

Also unchecked limit rows as putting a limit in every time I want to search the whole data set gets tiresome.